# ASP.NET MVC 4 Route Issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am having an issue with Routing. I am using the JavaScript function below to do a post to my controller StudentSearch. When I did a post, it only passed the first parameter. The page is null which is expected; however, the start and end Date have date values, but both parameters are both null. What am I missing here? I read the documentation and search online, and I have not had any success so far.

```
//Javascript function
 findStudent function()
  {  
    var SearchValue= $("#Search").val();
    var StartDate = $('#StartDate').val();
    var EndDate = $('#EndDate').val();

    var url = '@Url.Action("Search")';

    location.href = url + "/" + SearchValue + "/" + StartDate +"/" + EndDate+;
}

//This is the ActionResult in the controller
public ActionResult Search(string SearchValue, string StartDate , string EndDate)
  {
     //EndDate and STart Date are null here.
   }

//the route section in my RouteConfig.cs file

routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Search",
                url: "StudentSearch/Search/{SearchValue}/{StartDate}/{EndDate}",
                defaults: new { controller = "StudentSearch", action = "Search", 
                SearchValue = UrlParameter.Optional,StartDate=UrlParameter.Optional, 
                EndDate = UrlParameter.Optional}
                );
```

update at 02:50 PM:
After reading Chris comment, I modified the code. It did not route to the StudentSearch controller. I got a 404 page not found instead. As you can see I passed in Jane for searchvalue and student1, student2 respectively for start and enddate (it was not a problem since the parameter is expected a string).
.../StudentSearch/Search/Jane/student1/student2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're expecting here. The `url` variable is going to resolve to the string `'/StudentSearch/Search'`, because you're passing empty strings for all the route params. That's actually pointless, anyways. You'd get the same with just `@Url.Action("Search")`.

Then you append the variable `SearchValue` to this string, which comes form `$('#Search').val()`. And, that's it. `StartDate` and `EndDate` are never used, especially not in constructing the URL.

Then your route itself doesn't accept anything but `SearchValue` as a wildcard string. Even if you did append `StartDate` and `EndDate` to the URL, everything would just go into the `SearchValue` param and your actual `StartDate` and `EndDate` action parameters would still be null. Your route would need to be something like:

```
url: "StudentSearch/Search/{SearchValue}/{StartDate}/{EndDate}",
```

To fill all the parameters properly.

Comment: I was fighting and could not figure out why it was not working. I had to restart my computer because of some required updated. I ran the application again, and it worked.